# Using datetime.strptime with microseconds (ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00)

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert this date '2021-09-29 00:05:00+00:00' into "str" using the following code:

```
date1 = '2021-09-29 00:05:00+00:00'

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f')
```

but I get the error:

> "ValueError: unconverted data remains: :00".

I don't know how to deal with the microseconds. Any help to use strptime with that date format would be more than appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That’s not microseconds, but a time zone offset in hours and minutes.

Comment: What does the `00:00` actually mean? That definitely shouldn't be milliseconds, but I don't think it's a time zone offset neither.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I asked OP if they know what it is. I understand your assumption, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Use `%z` instead of `+%f`

Comment: @MarkTolonen tested it and yeah, you definitely have to be right. Didn't know that the standard representation of timezone offset in `strptime` with `%z` flag is `[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}`.

Answer (score 2):

The `+00:00` offset is a timezone offset in hours and minutes.  Per the [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) documentation, use `%z` to parse:

| Directive | Meaning | Example | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| %z | UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object is naive) | (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030, +063415, -030712.345216 | (6) |

Syntax for the colon(:) wasn't supported until Python 3.7, per a detail in note 6:

> *Changed in version 3.7:* When the `%z` directive is provided to the `strptime()` method, the UTC offsets can have a colon as a separator between hours, minutes and seconds. For example, `'+01:00:00'` will be parsed as an offset of one hour. In addition, providing `'Z'` is identical to `'+00:00'`.

```py
from datetime import datetime

s = '2021-09-29 00:05:00+00:00'
t = datetime.strptime(s,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
print(t)
```

Output:

```
2021-09-29 00:05:00+00:00
```